# req.file undefined for multer and body-parser with express API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer, body-parser

I'm writing an API that will have to deal with uploading files along with other GET, POST requests. I attempting to handle a file upload with `multer`, and use `body-parser` for any other HTTP Request. For any uploads I like to use the endpoint '/api/upload' which will utilize multer, and any other API call will used a route defined in `api.js`, which is also '/api' but for many other functions. Here is part of my `server.js` file that is setting up the server and routes:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const http = require( 'http' );
const path = require( 'path' );

const multer = require( 'multer' );
const upload = multer( { dest : '/uploads' } );

// create express app
const app = express();


// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: true } ) );

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use( bodyParser.json() );

...

const api_uploads = require( './server/routes/upload' );

app.use( '/api/upload', api_uploads );

// get API routes
const api = require( './server/routes/api' );

// set our api routes
app.use( '/api', api );


// catch all other routes and return the index file
app.get( '*', ( req, res ) =>
{
    res.sendFile( path.join( __dirname, 'dist/index.html' ) );
});

...
```

I'm storing all of my routes inside two different files: `upload.js` and `api.js`. `api.js` will house all the related functions that can use the `body-parser` for the request body, while `upload.js` will use `multer` to process any file uploads.

Here is my `api.js` file:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const entities = require( '../controllers/entity.controller.js' );

// default api listing
router.get('/', function(req, res) 
{
res.send('api works');

});

// Retrieve all Entities
router.get( '/', entities.findAll );

// Create a new Entity
router.post( '/', entities.create );

// search for entities
router.get( '/search', entities.find );

// download all available entities
router.get( '/download', entities.downloadAll );

// download specific entities
router.post( '/download', entities.download );

// Delete an Entity with entityId
router.delete( '/:entityId', entities.delete );

module.exports = router;
```

and my `upload.js` file:

```
const express = require( 'express' );
const router = express.Router();

const entities = require( '../controllers/entity.controller.js' );

router.post( '/', entities.upload );

module.exports = router;
```

The controller `entity.controller.js` contains all the API functions to process these calls.

```
var Entity = require( '../models/entity.model.js' );

const multer = require( 'multer' );
const upload = multer( { dest : '/uploads' } );

exports.findAll = function( req, res ) 
{
....
};

exports.create = function( req, res ) 
{
....
};

exports.find = function( req, res )
{
....
}

exports.downloadAll = function( req, res )
{
....
}

exports.download = function( req, res)
{
....
}

exports.upload = ( upload.single( 'entity' ), function( req, res )
{
    if( req.file )
    {
        console.log( 'file send successfully' );
        res.send( { message : 'thank you for the file' } );
    }
    else
    {
        res.status( 500 ).send( { message: "Some error occurred while acquiring file." } );
    }       
});

exports.delete = function( req, res ) 
{
....
};
```

I'm attempting to test my API by performing a POST request through Postman. Here is a snapshot of my request being sent: [image: postman POST request]

However, every time I check `req.file` inside of `exports.upload` it always returns `undefined`. I've seen other posts on stackoverflow, but they seemed to mostly be sticking with one middleware to parse the incoming request, where as I like to use `body-parser` for certain requests and `multer` for others involving file uploads. Is this possible, and based off my current setup what could I be doing wrong? Also though, if this is convoluted and unnecessary and if it would be better to stick with one parser then going between the two that works too.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify your code like this to work:

**server.js**

```
app.use( '/api/upload', upload.single('entity'), api_uploads );
```

**entity.controller.js**

```
exports.upload = function (req, res) {
    if (req.file) {
        console.log('file send successfully');
        res.send({
            message: 'thank you for the file'
        });
    } else {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: "Some error occurred while acquiring file."
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: I rearranged the code to do `app.use( bodyParser...` before setting the routes, but it is still throwing an error saying req.file is undefined.

Comment: unfortunately also undefined. I actually commented out the line that is setting the route for `/api` and just use the routes defined in `upload.js` to see if just having that file would work, but it also still saying it is undefined.

Comment: I've updated my post to include an image of my request to the API. I'm using Postman and hitting the `/api/entities/upload` endpoint to upload a file.

Comment: Ah I see, seems to be a weird issues where it has to be within the `server.js` file to run correctly, and can't be a route specified in another file? if you update your post I can mark it as answered.